# Time Not Displaying Properly in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, material-ui, date-fns

I wanted to display the time correctly based on the values i set in the `useState`. It should display `9:00 AM`. Why is it its is display `Invalid Time Format`.

Pls check my codesandbox here

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-benz-x234p?file=/src/App.jsx)

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
  <KeyboardTimePicker
    inputVariant="outlined"
    size="small"
    mask="__:__ _M"
    value={format(new Date(selectedTime), "hh:mm:00 a")}
    onChange={handleTimeChange}
    KeyboardButtonProps={{ disabled: true, style: { display: "none" } }}
  />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using a pretty old version of date-fns?

Comment: No, his problem is solved in my answer, you can try it in his codesandbox

Comment: @ThomasHoffner I was asking the OP if they're intentionally using an old version of date-fns. That question is unrelated to potential solutions.

Comment: The value you pass to `KeyboardTimePicker` needs to match the format *it* expects, not the format you would want it displayed as. The format string itself is fine, the error is coming from the picker component, not date-fns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit this part of your code:

```
value={format(new Date(selectedTime), "hh:mm:00 a")}
```

To this:

```
value={format(new Date(selectedTime), "yyyy-MM-dd''HH:mm:ss")}
```

Or this:

```
value={format(new Date(selectedTime), 3)}
```

And it should work well, check this link to documentation:
https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format

Comment: Noting that the OP is using version 1.3.13.